# SCIKIT FastICA Maximum Number of Iterations

Tags: python, scikit-learn, iteration, convergence

I'm getting the following error: "FastICA did not converge. Consider increasing tolerance or the maximum number of iterations".

So, considering the documentation here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FastICA.html , what is the maximum number of iterations that I can plug into the **max_iter** parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to increase your max_iter. I had this error and increased the tolerance (tol) though and it seemed to remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game, but this still might be helpful for someone.
I had the same error and increasing the max_iter parameter didn' actually help (it just took longer to get the same warning message).

What helped in my case was applying a stronger Highpass filter to the data (had to change it from 0.5Hz to 1Hz) before starting the ICA.